# Docker rmi unable to remove images

Tags: docker

So , I have a bunch of untagged images on my host. I use

`sudo docker rmi $(sudo docker images | grep "<none>" | awk '{print($3)}')`
to delete these images. On execution , I get error

> Error response from daemon: Conflict, cannot delete 31fa814ba25a
>   because the container 70c20aa2c19f is using it, use -f to force

So I do a

```
sudo docker rmi 70c20aa2c19f
```

on which I get the error

> Error response from daemon: No such image: 70c20aa2c19f

So if there's no image with ImageID 70c20aa2c19f , then why the initial delete command's error states that there is an image with ImageID 70c20aa2c19f ?

Comment: It says **the container 70c20aa2c19f is using it** is using it. Try removing the container first. `docker rm 70c20aa2c19f`

Comment: sudo docker ps doesnot show any running container

Comment: And what about `sudo docker ps -a`? Does it show any container?

Comment: Oh yeah, I get it now. There are a lot of containers when I do a sudo docker ps -a. I am gonna write a script to remove all the containers.

Comment: One question: The containers listed in ps -a are not running , if I get it right. If so , why  Docker would not let me delete the images?

Comment: You can use something like `sudo docker rm $(sudo docker ps -qa)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76980/discussion-between-dharmit-and-amrx).

Comment: @amrx because the container is stopped, but it is still there. You need to delete the container to be able to delete the images.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the comments on your question indicate, you have figured out that you need to use:

- `docker rmi` to remove images
- `docker rm` to remove containers

for a bit more background: there is a difference between:

1. A docker image,
2. A running container based off that image and
3. A stopped container based off that image

The stopped container **is kept** because running the container might have changed the file system in the container, you can then commit this stopped container to have a new image. (that's one way to create images, manually run the commands and commit the resulting container).

Creating images using docker build and Dockerfile, does the same thing, it runs the container executing the Dockerfile commands and commits the resulting images, only tagging the last image that was committed.

Comment: See the command docker image prune for removing unused images. There is also a command for removing unused volumes - docker volume prune.

Comment: @DanielEagle these commands were added in Docker 1.13 - yes

see also `docker system prune` to prune images, containers and volumes

Comment: I should have mentioned that they were newer commands but wanted to throw the comment out there to complement your answer. Thanks for the other command to take care of everything as that works rather well for those who don't want to type as much. :)

Answer (score 1):

The command below worked great for me, just keep adding the grep -v's for all the containers you **want to keep**:

```
sudo docker rm -f $(sudo docker ps -a -q | grep -v <good_container_1> | grep -v <good_container_2>)
```

Answer (score 0):

First You need to delete the containers belonging into docker image.
After you will delete the Docker image. I tried, its works fine.

Comment: This could have been submitted as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The message tells a container was using the image, and the container stopped, but the image is still attached with the container. To remove the image, first you need to remove the container by `docker rm [Container-ID]`. After this, remove the image by `docker rmi [Image-ID]`

Answer (score 0):

Didn't work for me. No containers created, but rmi claims that the image doesn't exist.

```
msoulier@deimos:~/work/mbgdocker$ docker images
REPOSITORY                   TAG              IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
multiarch/qemu-user-static   register         ed40092460e6   4 weeks ago   1.26MB
multiarch/qemu-user-static   x86_64-aarch64   04f21107bea2   4 weeks ago   9.83MB
msoulier@deimos:~/work/mbgdocker$ docker rmi 04f21107bea2
Error: No such image: 04f21107bea2
msoulier@deimos:~/work/mbgdocker$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
ode here
```